# gravity forms file upload field

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I have created sample form using gravity forms which has some fields with file upload field. when form loads, it will check for existing data and if there it will populate it from database.

1. Once user uploaded the file and clicks on submit button, the page being refreshed and showing "x" button(image) with file name which was uploaded, but how do I know user clicked on "x" button(user choose the remove button). Is there any hook or function, so in the next submit button I know the user wants to remove the previously uploaded file?
2. How to populate the existing file link in gravity forms which was uploaded)(if any) and give the user option to remove the file (some kind of button) otherwise show file upload field.

Could anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

1. **If your users uploading images are logged in**, you can try this with [Gravity View](https://gravityview.co/) (its a premium plugin). Once the user uploads the image they will be able to see or edit contents of the form.
2. **If users uploading images are not logged in:** Here is a guide that helps you this might be able to help you. 
   https://www.puddinq.com/blog/wordpress/gravity-forms-image-upload-preview/